# End of script output before headers (PHP & Apache)

Tags: php, apache, windows-server-2008

I was getting the following error occasionally. I've search through stackoverflow but all are due to other issue (either cgi or permission) If i can load the following page occassionally (about success 644,000 times in a day and failed 8,000 times.) then I'm sure it's not about permission.

I need to reload the following page stably every 15seconds.

> [Sat Aug 01 15:21:03.393569 2020] [core:error] [pid 9328:tid 15760] [client 127.0.0.1:52411] End of script output before headers: index.php, referer: http://127.0.0.1/Admin/index.php?type=14

The following is my apache setting for a 16 core, 32GB cloud instance. Running on windows server 2008 environment + apache 2.4 + PHP 7.0 ONLY. Page reload via chrome + super auto reload plus plugin.

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    MaxConnectionsPerChild 100000
    ThreadsPerChild 1920
</IfModule>

FcgidMaxRequestLen 51200000
KeepAliveTimeout 50
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
Timeout 600
```

The script is doing the calculation with PHP and refresh via timeout of JS.
JS refresh every 15s and the plugin refresh the entire page every 1 hour.
Any advice?